# Pivot created using PivotTableWizard displays (All) instead of (Multiple Items)

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am generating a Pivot table programmatically using the code below:

```
Set objTable = wb.PivotTableWizard
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot Table"

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("CURRENT_STATUS")
objField.Orientation = xlPageField
objField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
```

I set the visibility of some fields for the report filter using

```
With objTable.PivotFields("CURRENT_STATUS")
    For Each PvI In .PivotItems
        Select Case PvI.Name
        Case "A","B","C"
            PvI.Visible = False
        Case Else
            PvI.Visible = True
        End Select
    Next
End With
```

The Pivot is created correctly with only the required items selected, but the report filter shows (All) instead of (Multiple Items)

How can I get the pivot to show the text (Multiple Items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution

Explicitly setting ShowPageMultipleItemLabel property as "True" did the trick. Though the value should be True by default. Not sure why it was not so in this case.

```
objTable.ShowPageMultipleItemLabel = True
```